# Call excel function in access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've a sub in excel that needs to be called from access.
Excel vba

```
 Public Function testme(value As String) As String

 Dim xlpath As String
 Dim concate As String

 xlpath=ActiveWorkbook.Path
 value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 concate = xlpath & "\" & value     
 Let testme = concate

 End Function
```

i need to call above method in one of the access method.How do i call it.

```
 Sub Connect1()
 Dim xlApp As Variant
'Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'this will launch a blank copy of excel; you'll have to load workbooks
'xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Let ans = xlApp.Application.Run("MyXLVBAProject.MyXLVBAModule.testme", 400)
'here ans has the string "500"
End Sub
```

Comment: How has access opened the excel workbook?

Comment: You'll probably want to use Application.Run from Excel's object model.  You pass it a string such as "QuickRDA.JavaCallBacks.GetQuickTab" for the macro name, where QuickRDA is the name of the Excel VBA project, JavaCallBacks is the name of the VBA module in that VBA project, and GetQuickTab is the name of the function in that VBA module.

Comment: If possible could you please give me code sample

Comment: In the code sample you're showing above, you pass in a flname parameter as a string, but then assign another value to it, wiping it out.  (Also, it doesn't get used either.) Further you omit assigning a return value to function passfilename.  Perhaps you wanted `passfilename = ActiveWorkbook.Path` to return the path?

Comment: Ok, I see your update.  It looks to me like you don't need to pass a parameter to `testme` from access.  Therefore, I suggest you change `value` from a formal parameter to a local variable.  You can omit the actual parameter in the call as well.  I will update my answer to show you exactly what I mean.

Comment: My pleasure.  Cheers and happy programming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use Application.Run from Excel's object model. You pass it a string such as "QuickRDA.JavaCallBacks.GetQuickTab" for the macro name, where QuickRDA is the name of the Excel VBA project, JavaCallBacks is the name of the VBA module in that VBA project, and GetQuickTab is the name of the function in that VBA module.

In Access

```
Sub Connect()    
    Dim xlApp As Variant
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    'this will connect to an already open copy of excel, a bit easier for quick & dirty testing
    Let ans = xlApp.Application.Run("MyXLVBAProject.MyXLVBAModule.testme")
End Sub
```

In Excel

```
Public Function testme() As String
    Dim xlpath As String
    Dim concate As String
    Dim value as String
    xlpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    concate = xlpath & "\" & value     
    Let testme = concate
End Function
```

-or simply-

```
Public Function testme() As String
    Let testme = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
End Function
```

Remember that in Excel the function testme should be put in a module whose name is MyXLVBAModule, and that the project containing the module should be called MyXLVBAProject.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: but i wanted to pass file name in the place of 400 above code.**ans** is not returning filename

Comment: Ok, you can pass your string instead of 400, of course, and, don't forget to change `value as Long` to `value as String` in testme (as well as returning the string of interest, of course).  Also, please have a look at my 2nd comment to your question above.

Comment: I've changed my code based on your code.please have look my question. but instead of 400 what should i pass? please help me.I need to pass **concate** to access.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to trigger an Excel function from Access, or run an Excel subroutine from Access?

To run a function, you can do something like this.

```
  Public Function FV(dblRate As Double, intNper As Integer, _ 
                  dblPmt As Double, dblPv As Double, _ 
                  intType As Integer) As Double
     Dim xl As Object
     Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     FV = xl.WorksheetFunction.FV(dblRate, intNper, dblPmt, dblPv, intType)
     Set xl = Nothing
 End Function
```

[image]

To run an Excel subroutine from Access, you can do the following.

```
Sub RunExcelMacro()
Dim xl As Object
'Step 1:  Start Excel, then open the target workbook.
   Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Book1.xlsm")
'Step 2:  Make Excel visible
   xl.Visible = True
'Step 3:  Run the target macro
   xl.Run "MyMacro"
'Step 4:  Close and save the workbook, then close Excel
   xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    xl.Quit
'Step 5:  Memory Clean up.
   Set xl = Nothing 
End Sub
```